# Python–Object AttributeError when accessing class attribute python

Tags: python, object, inheritance, pygame, subclassing

I have three classes: `Item`, `Weapon`, and `BrassSword`
When I try to access one of `BrassSword`'s attributes ex.(name,image,etc.) It says, `AttributeError: class BrassSword has no attribute 'image'`

Here's the code:

```
import pygame, math, random

class Item(object):
    def __init__(self,name,image,reuseable,value):
        self.image=pygame.image.load(image)
        self.itemattrs = ['name','image','reuseable','value']
        self.path = image
        self.name = name
        self.x=0
        self.y=0
        self.reusable = reuseable
        self.value = value
        self.rect = [self.x,self.y,self.image.get_size()[0],self.image.get_size()[1]]
    def onUse(self):
        pass
    def onThrow(self):
        pass

class Weapon(Item):
    def __init__(self,name,image,value,damage,maxdamage,speed):
        super(Weapon,self).__init__('Weapon',image,True,value)
        self.itemattrs = ['name','image','damage','maxdamage','value','speed']
        self.damage=damage
        self.maxdamage=maxdamage
        self.speed = speed # Cooldown in frames
        self.cooldown = 0
    def onUpdate(self):
        self.cooldown -= 1
    def onUse(self,targetEntity):
        if self.cooldown > 0:
            return
        self.cooldown = speed
        targetEntity.hp-=random.range(damage,maxdamage)

        if targetEntity.hp <= 0:
            targetEntity.onDie()
    def onThrow(self):
        pass # TODO: Add throwing weapons

class BrassSword(Weapon):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BrassSword,self).__init__('item.weapon.brass_sword','testlevel/Ball.png',True,value,3,10,12)
```

Comment: Executing a `self.attrs = ['name','image','reuseable','value']` gives an instance of a class an attribute named `attrs` that is a list of strings, _not_ separate attributes named 'name', 'image', 'reuseable', and 'value'.

Comment: why are you passing `self` as a first argument to `__init__` when using `super`?

Comment: Oops. Thanks, people.

Comment: Fixed everything, but it still crashes `AttributeError: class BrassSword has no attribute 'image'`

Comment: edit the question reposting the code, please

Comment: I did. Try refreshing the page.

Comment: in all your classes the call to `super` is still wrong. You call `super` passing it the parent class, not the present class. Use `super(thepresentclass,self).__init__(...`

Comment: I changed it. No luck.

Comment: read my comment above again. All your calls to `super` are wrong. Do as you did on BronzeSword on all of them

Comment: Your `Weapon`.`__init__` is calling super `Weapon` instead of `Item`

Comment: I mean to call Weapon, because BrassSword is a subclass of Weapon

Comment: Renaming `attrs` to `itemattrs` didn't accomplish anything.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use subclassing often in Python, so sorry if this question sounds dumb.

Comment: Please post the code that you use when you try to access the attribute.

Comment: Still some existing issues:

Comment: you passthrough a `value` attribute in the `BrassSword` constructor but `value` is undefined

Comment: your `Item` class needs to inherit from `object` (new-style classes) or `super()` won't work correctly

Comment: `self` should not be the first argument in `super()` call inside `Weapon`

Comment: In `super(BrassSword,self).__init__('item.weapon.brass_sword','testlevel/Ball.png',True,value,3,10,12)` the name `value` is undefined, and `Weapon.__init__()` does not take that many arguments. Please only post code that is syntactically correct.

Comment: http://pastie.org/private/rs8l8qj6xqpapcinkswnw this works for me, example output included -- your brassword call to super contains too many values btw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't post the code that's actually causing the error - namely where you access the attribute. However, you can't access an instance attribute by referring to the class - they are stored in a separate `__dict__`. Your superclass sets these attributes when it is instantiated in `__init__()`, as a property of `self`. After this, they can only be accessed through that `self` instance.

If you are trying to access the attribute similarly to this:

```
a = BrassSword.image
```

instead, you want to access it something like this:

```
sword = BrassSword()
a = sword.image
```

or:

```
sword = BrassSword().image
```

If you want to have a single image shared across all BrassSword instances, you need to declare it a class attribute like this:

```
class BrassSword(Weapon):
    image = 'path/to/image'
    def __init__(...):
        ...
```